# If $X, Y \sim N(0,1)$ are iid rv, then $U=\frac{X Y}{\sqrt{X^{2}+Y^{2}}} \sim N(0,1 / 4)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

I need to prove that if $X$ and $Y$ are iid $N(0,1)$ random variables, then $U=\frac{X Y}{\sqrt{X^{2}+Y^{2}}} \sim N(0,1 / 4)$.

I know that:

- $U=\frac{\left(\frac{X+Y}{2}\right)^2-\left(\frac{X-Y}{2}\right)^2}{\sqrt{X^2 + Y^2}}$;
- $\left(\frac{X+Y}{2}\right)^2, \left(\frac{X-Y}{2}\right)^2$ follows a chi-squared distribution with parameter 1;
- $X^2 + Y^2 \sim \chi_2^2$ follows a chi-squared distribution with parameter 2.
  But I don't know how to move forward from this or even if this is the right path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can express in polar coordinates:
$$
\begin{aligned}
X &= R \cos \Theta \\
Y &= R \sin \Theta
\end{aligned}
$$
Where $R,\Theta$ are independent and $\Theta \sim U(0, 2\pi)$, that is, uniformly distributed on the interval $(0, 2\pi)$. (We could define $\Theta$ differently but this will do.) Then by the double angle formula we have:
$$
U = \frac{1}{2} R \sin 2 \Theta
$$
Since $\sin$ is $2\pi$-periodic and $\Theta$ is uniformly distributed, $\sin 2\Theta$ is identically distributed to $\sin \Theta$. And since $R$ and $\Theta$ are independent $R \sin 2\Theta$ is identically distributed to $R \sin \Theta$. Hence $2U = R \sin 2\Theta \sim N(0,1)$ and $U \sim N(0,1/4)$.

Note we don't need to know much about the distribution of $R$ other than the above relationship to the normal distribution.